# Financial status

Tags: visas

I need a help to make a decision. Will I be granted a visa from Ghana to live with my wife who is German (born in Germany) after she has come down to Ghana for us to marry here? We have required documents but she has financial problems in Germany. Can her financial status prevent me from getting a visa?

Comment: Being born in Germany has little to do with one's citizenship. Until very recently German citizenship was usually inherited regardless of birthplace.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a complicated question, which is generally best asked on Expatriates stack exchange.

As I understand it, **yes**, her financial status may be considered among many other things, but less so than for a non-citizen resident of Germany. [§28 AutenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__28.html) gives exceptions to [§5 (1) 1](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__5.html), but it uses the word "soll" (should be) which leaves some latitude to the official how to apply the law in accordance with administrative regulations and precedent.

Comment: Please if I should add to my question, her current status is good but about a year ago , she was owing which she couldn't pay so she declared herself bankrupt which as a result she can't even buy an item on credit . The government has taken her bills. Can that bankruptcy declaration be used to deny me of a family reunion visa?

Comment: @o.S, ask the question on Expatriates. What you explain seems to be a *Privatinsolvenz*, which requires her to make a good faith attempt to repay debts for seven years. How can she travel to Ghana in that case?

Comment: Its not a bank dept but buying clothes and other things from online on credit and she could pay all of them .

Comment: Yes that's the word . Insolvenz